# Modifying a WritebleWorkbook already exits with java

Tags: java, excel, jxl

My problem is to write on an Excel workbook! But my program controls if the file already exists! If the file exists then write on the next free cell, else create the file!
I tried with:

```
    private WritableWorkbook wwb;
    try
    {

        file = new File(filename);
        System.out.println("File" + file.toString());
        if(file.exists())
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Il file esiste!");
            wwb.setOutputFile(file);
            fileExist=true;
        }
        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Il file non esiste!Quindi lo creo");
            fileExist=false;
            WorkbookSettings wbSettings = new WorkbookSettings();
            wbSettings.setLocale(new Locale("it", "IT"));
            wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File((filename)), wbSettings);
            wwb.createSheet("Ticket", 0);
        } 
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       System.out.println(ex.getStackTrace());
    }
```

The problem is a NullPointerException that I think is on the line:

```
    wwb.setOutputFile(file);
```

I tried to search javadocs on WritableWorkbook but I see that there aren't constructors!
How can i do this? Please help.
I'm using the jxl API.

Answer (score 0):

Need to initialise the object due to which you are facing null pointer exception at

```
 wwb.setOutputFile(file);
```

Comment: I know man! I tryed it! But when i write:
        wwb= new WritableWorkbook();
Java compiler sign an error...the error is that i ve to implements all abstract method of WritableWorkbook!

Comment: cant understand dear.plz exaplain

Comment: I can't use web= new WritableWorkbook() for initialize wwb! How can i write on excel sheet? That already exist and i don t want overwrite it! I wanna open the excel workbook and then write on it in the first free cell